# Facebook share in a website (get value from textbox)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am in a process of building my very first website and I came into some problems when trying to implement Facebook Share into my site.

What I am trying to accomplish is: 
1) Get URL from textbox in my site.
2) Share it on Facebook.

This is the code I tried:

```
<center><a href="#" class="ssk ssk-text ssk-facebook ssk-m" data-url="getElementById("name").value" data-text="">Share in Facebook</a>
```

It works with:

```
<center><a href="#" class="ssk ssk-text ssk-facebook ssk-m" data-url="http://website.com" data-text="">Share in Facebook</a>
```

But I need it to work with dynamic textbox text. For same URL, it works fine.

But it doesn't work with my first code example and I get this error message on Facebook Share popup:

```
href should represent a valid URL
```

This is image of the error:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L97O.png]

Thanks, I hope I will find help here.

Comment: if you look at the url in the image you provided youll see that the url did not get the value but rather just took the whole text that you have entered in the data-url. so you probably want a button instead and when you enter a url have an event that will read from that textbox and append it to the data-url value

Comment: could you please give me more details... I am very new....